# Does JHipster 7.9.3 support Java 17, Spring boot 3 and Spring Framework 6?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I am using JHipster 7.9.3 in my current project using Java 11, Spring Boot 2.7. We are now in the process of upgrading to Java 17, Spring Boot 3 and Spring Framework 6 and I see the following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'openAPIDefaultGroupedOpenAPI' defined in class path resource [tech/jhipster/config/apidoc/JHipsterSpringDocGroupsConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'openAPIDefaultGroupedOpenAPI' parameter 3: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfigProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Am I missing anything?. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No. Spring Boot 3 is only supported by JHipster 8. You can install the v8 RC1 version using `npm i -g generator-jhipster`. You can try `jhipster upgrade` and see if it works. If it doesn't please enter an issue in the JHipster GitHub project.

Comment: It does work with Java 17

Comment: @MattRaible - I am able to install 8.0.0-rc.1 on my local machine. But I would like to add it in pom.xml. I tried this <jhipster-dependencies.version>8.0.0-rc.1</jhipster-dependencies.version> but unable to get it to work. Is this version right?

Comment: You can see the `jhipster-bom` versions at https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-bom/releases.